# Parallel Curve Function

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I understand that every curve has two parallel curves for any given distance: one on both sides.

Finding parallel curves to some algebraic objects are simple, especially lines and circles ($P(y,d)$ means the parallel curve to curve $y$ at uniform distance $d$).

Lines:$$y=mx+b$$$$P(y,d)=(mx+b)±(d*\sqrt{1 + m^2})$$

Circles:$$y=±\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$$$P(y,d)=±\sqrt{(r±d)^2-x^2}$$

Is there any theorem, law, etc. to determine any arbitrary algebraically-defined curve, such as parabolas, hyperbolas, ellipses, exponential functions, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we denote by $\mathbf{t} $ and $\mathbf{n} $ respectively the 
unit tangent and (outward) normal vectors
$$
\mathbf{t} = \frac{1}
{{\sqrt {dx^{\,2}  + dy^{\,2} } }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {dx}  \\
   {dy}  \\
 \end{array} } \right)\quad \mathbf{n} = \frac{1}
{{\sqrt {dx^{\,2}  + dy^{\,2} } }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {dy}  \\
   { - dx}  \\
 \end{array} } \right)
$$
the parametric equation of the parallell curves shall be
(changing $d$ to $s$, to avoid confusion with the differential)
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x_p  = x(\lambda ) \pm s\,n_{\,x}  = x(\lambda ) \pm s\,\frac{{dy}}
{{\sqrt {dx^{\,2}  + dy^{\,2} } }} \hfill \\
  y_p  = y(\lambda ) \pm s\,n_{\,y}  = y(\lambda ) \mp s\,\frac{{dx}}
{{\sqrt {dx^{\,2}  + dy^{\,2} } }} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
By putting $x(\lambda)=\lambda$, or by other algebraic means
the above can be converted to the case of having $y=y(x)$ or
$F(x,y)=0)$

Comment: I am used to parametric equations in the {x(t)=~, y(t)=~} form. Is λ (lambda) merely an exact replacement of "t," or does it represent some special case? and where was the "t" used in the parametric equation down below?

Comment: Yes, $\lambda$ is the parameter describing the original curve: you can call it with whatever other name, including $t$ if you are more familiar with it (apart that it is normally associated with the parameter representing  time). For your 2nd question, I do not get what you mean.